# Cannot Forward IP and portnumber to another IP address

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I am trying to forward the packets to another internal IP address in AWS. (Linux).

My scenario is Gateway(EC2)(9.19.22.22) and two internal IP address (10.0.0.5) and (10.0.0.6).

```
The packet coming to to 10.0.0.5 on 10009 from 17.16.0.99 (all) to be forwarded to 10.0.0.6 on 10010 port number.

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 17.16.0.99/32 --dport 10009 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.6:10010
```

I tried pre-routing but seems not to be working

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to either:

1. Configure routing in `10.0.0.6` so that packets leaving from port `10010` are forwarded to `10.0.0.5`.
2. Add a masquerade rule at `10.0.0.5`, which replaces packet source address with `10.0.0.5`. An example would be `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --dport 10009 -j MASQUERADE`

In both cases you need to make sure IP forwarding is enabled, that is `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` shows `1`.